# Is there a Regular Expression that will never match any string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Sort of a two part question:

1. Is there any theoretical regular expression that will never match any string (using general syntax without any fancy stuff provided by modern regular expression matchers)?
2. Is there a simple way to use C#'s Regex syntax to create a regex that will never match any string (this time, all the fancy stuff *is* included)?

NOTE: I am **not** referring to matching the empty string (that would be easy, just `""`).

Comment: Do you consider lookarounds to be new and fancy?

Comment: @DavidPärsson Yes I do. But that could work for the second part.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This will match empty string. JS: `"".match(/$^/)`

Comment: Is this question purely theoretical, or is there any use case for a regex that matches nothing? I can't see it.

Comment: @DavidPärsson Given that you need a string to match against, there's no point in doing so since you already know the result.

Comment: @DavidPärsson There is a use: To construct a regex that matches any string from a given list, you just escape each string and concatenate them with "|". But if the list is empty, I want to make sure the regex matches nothing. Of course there are ways around this but this way I think is better.

Comment: Matt, while getting an answer to this particular question is of some value, you should consider [**asking a question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about your true problem, instead of asking how to make your solution for it work ;) The most trivial solution, if you want to keep your regex approach, is to check whether the list is empty.

Comment: @phant0m duh you have to check. But the function has to return a regex even if the list is empty.

Comment: @Matt I think he's saying there's ways to refactor this, for example returning two values, one being a bool telling whether there was a regex, and the second being the regex (or take a regex by reference in C#, or return `null` or something like that) instead of always returning a sometimes useless regex. The calling code gets messier but more "consistent".

Comment: @SethCarnegie I would disagree, the calling code gets messier and LESS consistent. Like I said, I know there are ways to refactor it (in fact I don't even have to return two values because I can just return null), but I think this way is best and most consistent way because the regex does what it is supposed to do no matter whether the list is empty or not. It is basically a base case for the logical OR operation (the OR of an empty list is `false`).

Comment: @DavidPärsson Another reason is if you are implementing the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) - perhaps you've got a config value that specifies a regex, but if it's not set you want to return a regex that matches nothing, rather than `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as you can match any characters with `[\s\S]`, you can match no characters with `[^\s\S]` (or `[^\w\W]`, etc).

Comment: @Matt sometimes `.` doesn't match newlines so I think it's safer to do `[^\s\S]` but I'm not a regex pro.

Answer (score 8):

Without multi-line mode, the end doesn't usually tend to appear before the beginning:

```
$.^
```

Or more simply, again without multi-line mode:

```
$.
```

With lookarounds, you can do all kinds of contradictory stuff:

```
(?=a)(?=b)
```

This forces a character to be two different things at once, which is of course impossible.

Comment: C# also has `\A` and `\Z` that match the beginning and end of a string respectively regardless of line breaks or multi-line mode. So would `\Z\A` work or would it have to be `\Z.\A`?

Comment: @Matt `\Z\A` [**matches the empty string ("1 match")**](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=48a705ab-e9d4-4694-951e-425daeb6a69c), so it would have to include some pattern that consumes at least one character between the two. A `.` was the most simple I could think of.

Comment: What I was really asking was does `\Z\A` match the empty string. And according to your test, it does.

Answer (score 5):

You could use contradictory lookbehinds, for example

```
\w(?<!\w)
```

Here `\w` will match any word character and the lookbehind `(?<!\w)` will make sure that the last character was not a word.

Comment: That might qualify as "fancy stuff"

Comment: Is that correct C# syntax? I've never heard of lookarounds before.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, please see [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookbehind_assertion)