# Fastest regular expression that does not match any string

Tags: python, regex

What is the fastest performing regular expression that does not match *any* string? It may seem like a useless thing, but consider a program that takes a *mandatory* regex as a filter for instance (this is actually my scenario). I've tried a few and found `b(?<!b)` to be the best performer given that `b` occurs rarely in the input.

Here is a python code I wrote to test different patterns for their speed:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import time

tests = [
  r'a\A',
  r'b\A',
  r'a^',
  r'b^',
  r'[^\s\S]',
  r'^(?<=a)',
  r'^(?<=b)',
  r'a(?<!a)',
  r'b(?<!b)',
  r'\Za',
  r'\Zb',
  r'$a',
  r'$b'
]
timing = []
text = 'a' * 50000000

for t in tests:
  pat = re.compile(t)
  start = time.time()
  pat.search(text)
  dur = time.time() - start
  timing.append((t, dur))

timing.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
print('%-30s %s' % ('Pattern', 'Time'))
for t, dur in timing:
  print('%-30s %0.3f' % (t, dur))
```

On my machine, I get the following times:

```
Pattern                        Time
b(?<!b)                        0.043
b\A                            0.043
b^                             0.043
$a                             0.382
$b                             0.382
^(?<=a)                        0.395
\Za                            0.395
\Zb                            0.395
^(?<=b)                        0.414
a\A                            0.437
a^                             0.440
a(?<!a)                        0.796
[^\s\S]                        1.469
```

*update: added benchmark for some of suggested regexes.*

Comment: @Gumbo `^(?<=x)` runs at `0.432`

Comment: It is unfair comparison for `b(?<!b)` and `a(?<!a)`, since your test string contains of only `a`. And how do you "fastest" here? Your test is only designed to find the fastest that doesn't match the string aa..a.

Comment: @nhahtdh It is not unfair when you compare it to `\Zb` which I expected to perform the fastest. `b(?<!b)` is the best case scenario. Also, picking a character like null character (`\0`) makes it very practical for text input.

Comment: @nhahtdh regexes that _don't_ match are what I'm after.

Comment: @Mansour: In benchmarking, people test the CPU against a **distribution** of instructions that is likely to be that of a typical program, etc. You didn't specify what kind of distribution of input that you want to benchmark against, so I would assume that all possible string input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Regular Expression that will never match any string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606550/is-there-a-regular-expression-that-will-never-match-any-string)

Comment: @phant0m: I don't think this is a duplicate. First of all, the programming language is different. Secondly this question is specifically about the fastest regex whereas the other question is about any.

Comment: @NPE Sure, but since this answer will change with time anyway and is pretty localized, he just needs to test different varieties of RegExes, and in that question he has a couple of things he can try.

Comment: @nhahtdh fair point. You can assume all possible string inputs. Of course, when testing, only a finite number of strings can be checked. I picked the best and worst case scenarios.

Comment: @Mansour: There's something slightly odd about the benchmark itself. When I time the same regexes on the same input using IPython's `%timeit`, I get *vastly* different timings. Puzzling.

Comment: @phant0m: Sure, but none of this makes it a *duplicate*.

Comment: updated the question with benchmark for `[^\s\S]` from the question pointed to by @phant0m as well as @Gumbo's `^(?<=x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single character is a valid regular expression.  A single character that is not "magic" matches itself.  If you can identify a single character that will never, ever appear in your text, you could make a pattern from that.

How about ASCII NUL, character 0?

I stuck in one more string in your test program, the string: `'\0'`

It was about as fast as your best pattern: `b(?<!b)`

Okay, you already have a character after the end of the string.  How about a character *before* the start of the string?  That's impossible:  `'x^'`

Aha!  That's faster than checking for a character after end of string.  But it's about as fast as your best pattern.

I suggest replacing the `b` with an ASCII NUL and calling it good.  When I tried that pattern: `\0(?<!\0)`

It wins by a tiny fraction.  But really, on my computer, all the ones discussed above are so close together that there isn't much to distinguish them.

Results:

```
Pattern                        Time
\0(?<!\0)                      0.098
\0                             0.099
x^                             0.099
b(?<!b)                        0.099
^(?<=x)                        1.416
$b                             1.446
$a                             1.447
\Za                            1.462
\Zb                            1.465
[^\s\S]                        2.280
a(?<!a)                        2.843
```

That was *fun*.  Thanks for posting the question.

EDIT: Ah *hah*!  I rewrote the program to test with real input data, and got a different result.

I downloaded "The Complete Works of William Shakespeare" from Project Gutenberg as a text file.  (Weird, it gave an error on `wget` but let my browser get it... some sort of measure to protect against automated copying?)  URL: http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt

Here are the results, followed by the modified program as I ran it.

```
Pattern                        Time
\0(?<!\0)                      0.110
\0                             0.118
x^                             0.119
b(?<!b)                        0.143
a(?<!a)                        0.275
^(?<=x)                        1.577
$b                             1.605
$a                             1.611
\Za                            1.634
\Zb                            1.634
[^\s\S]                        2.441
```

So yeah I'm definitely going with that first one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import time

tests = [
  r'x^',
  r'\0',
  r'[^\s\S]',
  r'^(?<=x)',
  r'a(?<!a)',
  r'b(?<!b)',
  r'\0(?<!\0)',
  r'\Za',
  r'\Zb',
  r'$a',
  r'$b'
]
timing = []
#text = 'a' * 50000000
text = open("/tmp/pg100.txt").read()
text = text * 10

for t in tests:
  pat = re.compile(t)
  start = time.time()
  pat.search(text)
  dur = time.time() - start
  timing.append((t, dur))

timing.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
print('%-30s %s' % ('Pattern', 'Time'))
for t, dur in timing:
  print('%-30s %0.3f' % (t, dur))
```

Comment: It is possible to throw in example to make the `\0` matches, and make `\0(?<!\0)`, `x^`, `b(?<!b)` slows down to other.

Comment: single character regexes _can_ match some string, so they aren't really correct answers. As for `\0(?<!\0)`, that's what I've been using and it's as good as it gets so far. Seeing your `x^`, I thought `a\A` on my original input would be the fastest but it's not. I'm confused as to why the engine keeps looking after the first character. `\A` only matches at the start.

Comment: @Mansour: Good so far, since you are assuming that `\0` won't appear in text. If you say that you assume the text won't contain `\0`, then it is fair. But no assumption = anything goes. So I can specify `\0` * big number and it will comes in last.

Comment: @nhahtdh I understand that! We just talked about it. That's why my test string is all `a`s and I have two copies of each pattern, one matching `a` and one one matching `b`. Best and worst case. If you want to find which pattern is input agnostic, look for `a` and `b` patterns with similar timing, which are the ones with anchors.

Comment: @steveha I'd have to say, `a\A` is the best so far, because overall (best and worst case scenario), it's the fastest.

Comment: @Mansour: Right. The ones with anchors are input-agnostic. Well, it is possible to conclude that `\0(?<!\0)` is the best, if you assume the `\0` to not appear anywhere in the text, or it is very rare to encounter the worse case and it is alright to spend a bit more time. The input-agnostic would be best if you don't want the timing to change regardless of what the input is. Any conclusion out of this would have to be made with assumption and precise description of what is best.

Comment: I just realized I did a silly thing while tired last night: I tried to test with ASCII NUL by putting `\0` inside a raw string.  Oops.  So the regex compiler was seeing a backslash and a `0` instead of a NUL.  I tried again and it didn't really make a big difference though.  Anyway I suggest using this:  `'\0' + r'\A'`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not exactly the sort of answer you're looking for, but I fiddled around with this for a few minutes and the best I could do is something like: `'a{%d}' % (len(input)+1)`. Or, in other words, *calculate your pattern to be any character with a max quantifier longer than the known length of the string*. This obviously only works if you have access to the input string. It appears to scale pretty nicely as well; I took the texts variable out to `texts = [os.urandom(20000) for x in range(20000)]` and in that case `a{20001}` still clocked in at `0.013`.

I haven't, however, calculated the cost of the operations to get the string length and generate the pattern, which you'd obviously have to deal with in the wild.

Updated script:

```
import os
import re
import time

tests = [
  r'\0(?<!\0)',
  r'\0',
  r'x^',
  r'a{2001}',
  r'a(?<!a)',
  r'b(?<!b)',
  r'\Za',
  r'\Zb',
  r'$a',
  r'$b'
]
texts = [os.urandom(2000) for x in range(20000)]
flag = 0

for t in tests:
    pat = re.compile(t)
    start = time.time()
    for text in texts:
        if pat.search(text):
            print('%-30s %10s' % (t, "FAILED"))
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag == 0:
        dur = time.time() - start
        print('%-30s %0.3f' % (t, dur))
    else:
        flag = 0
```

Benchmarks:

```
\0(?<!\0)                      0.058
\0                                 FAILED
x^                             0.055
a{2001}                        0.022
a(?<!a)                        0.060
b(?<!b)                        0.073
\Za                            0.798
\Zb                            0.797
$a                             0.757
$b                             0.767
```

Comment: `\0(?<!\0)`, `\0`, `x^`, `a{2001}`, `a(?<!a)`, `b(?<!b)` are input dependent. You can say it is the fastest for a random string, but with specially crafted string, it won't stay at that low value.

Comment: Ah. In the light of day I realize my answer of `a{len+1}` only works up to `a{65,535}`, meaning it would fail on the OP's test.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we use the short and convenient `(?!)` which fails directly.

If you want to be more explicit Perl/PCRE has the `(*FAIL)` or `(*F)` verb you can use.

Comment: Well, it is quite slow, though, at least from my computer.

Comment: This is interesting. I'm not even sure how it works. Empty negative lookahead? Also, it's rather slow at `0.622`, so I guess the python implementation isn't as smart here.

Comment: @Mansour: That's a negative look-ahead on empty string. Empty string is everywhere in between the text, so if you don't match empty string, then there will be no match.

Comment: @Mansour, empty string will always match, invert that with a negative lookahead to always fail.